# Where can I find Italc2 packages?

Tags: remote-control

I checked from [packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=italc&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and I se, that even Ubuntu 12.04 contains old version even Italc2 [has been released already half year ago](http://sourceforge.net/projects/italc/files/italc2/)... Is there any hope, that it will be renewed?

Answer (score 1):

According to this bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/italc/+bug/912884 there is no interest in upgrading iTalc to version 2 until Debian does. Also in that bug report is notice that Epoptes has replaced iTalc in edubuntu. Try that or you can build your own from source http://sourceforge.net/projects/italc/files/italc2/2.0.0/